# Creating Userform in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to paste the userfrom data into anothersheet that is "Stock In by Invoices" but it keep giving me an error enter correct date.

below attached picture is the sheet where i want to paste the data downward red highlighted cells are those cells where data will paste. please help in this regard.

I am also unable to change the getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5) Columns reference.

```
   function SubmitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stock In by Invoices");
  
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("J5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J15").getValue()]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 5).setValues(values);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You want to paste to a **non-contiguous** range. Therefore, you can
  instead separate the first value of `values` from the rest values.
- In your approach you start pasting from column 1 but that is not what you want. Please have a look at [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).
- Also when defining a range it is always a good idea to use the length
  of the data you want to set:

  ```
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 6, values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
  ```

---

### Solution:

Assuming that `getLastRow()` returns the correct number, this should work:

```
function SubmitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stock In by Invoices");
  var L_row = datasheet.getLastRow();

  var value = formSS.getRange("J5").getValue();
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("J7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J15").getValue()]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(L_row+1,4).setValue(value);
  datasheet.getRange(L_row+1, 6, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

If `getLastRow()` doesn't work because you have formulas or cells with contents in other columns, then try this approach:

```
function SubmitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stock In by Invoices");
  var n_filled_rows = datasheet.getRange('D:D').getValues().filter(String).length +3;  

  var value = formSS.getRange("J5").getValue(); 
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("J7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J13").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J15").getValue()]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(n_filled_rows+1,4).setValue(value);
  datasheet.getRange(n_filled_rows+1, 6, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```